# URL which returns country list in json format

Tags: ios, jsonp

Can anyone suggest URL which returns countries in json format.

Thanx in advance

Comment: This question doesnot belong here...Google is your friend !!! :)

Comment: I searched on google but unable to get proper link. Also the json should able to return the update of countries also.

Comment: Searched on Google and found this:- http://www.freeformatter.com/iso-country-list-html-select.html Does this help??

Comment: Sorry. It didn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get latest version of official ISO country  into JSON.

[This is URL 1](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists.htm)

[This is URL 2](http://www.tweetegy.com/2011/02/how-to-get-a-semantic-list-of-all-countries-and-locations-in-the-world/)

[This is URL 3](http://docs.shopify.com/api/country)

Comment: Thank you :) URL 2 works for my requirement